Ошибка filenotfounderror
Как проверить если пользователь захотел сразу посмотреть историю, ошибка filenotfounderror, не пойму как это сделать
with open('chat_log.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as chat:
    chat.writelines('Чат:\n')
def chat(chatfile):
        global name, act
        while True:
            try:
                name = input('Введите имя: ')
                act = int(input('''1 - Посмотреть текущий текст чата
    2 - Отправить сообщение
    Введите нужный вариант: '''))
                if act == 1:
                    with open(chatfile, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
                        print(file.read())
                else:
                    raise FileNotFoundError
                    print('\nИстория сообщений пуста.')
            #except FileNotFoundError:
                #print('\nИстория сообщений пуста. ')
            try:
                if act == 2:
                    with open(chatfile, 'a', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
                        message = input('Сообщение: ')
                        file.writelines(f'{str(name)}: {str(message)}\n')
            except ValueError:
                print('\nДействуйте по инструкции.')
    
    chat('chat_log.txt')


Не понятно что вы хотите сделать и что вы делаете... Напишите чётче в чем заключается ваша проблема и как устроен ваш код

Ну оберните первый if тоже в try/except )  А вообще тут весь код нужно переделывать
